# remove element in list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In a big dictionary, similar to

```
d = {}                                                                                   
d['a']=[1,2,3,4]                                                                         
d['b']=[1,2,3,4,5,6]                                                                     
d['c']=[1,2]                                                                             
d['d']=[1,4]
```

how can I quickly remove the 'four' in the lists ?

#### EDIT

Is there a way to link the fours in the lists? As in, eliminating one eliminates the others.

Answer (score 9):

Iterate over the values of the dictionary and remove the 4 from every list:

```
for a in d.values():
    try:
        a.remove(4)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This is not really efficient, since removing an element from a list is an O(n) operation.  Use a different data type (e.g. a set) for better performance.

If the dictionary values are sets, you can do

```
for a in d.values():
    a.discard(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove all 4s:

```
for i in d:
    while 4 in d[i]:
       d[i].remove(4)
```

I don't know a way that you can eliminate all 4s at once.

Comment: Not only is the code incorrect, it would also be an incredibly redundantly inefficient approach if it were correct. (`.remove()` does not take an index; that is `.pop()` which does that. Also mutating a list while you are iterating over it is a bad idea. Finally, `in` on a list requires iterating over it anyways, adding an extra `if` statement to check if the value you want to remove is in the list isn't more efficient, it actually makes things take longer.)

Comment: @Amber Thanks for pointing that out. Got confused by things. :( What about using `while 4 in d[i]`? any suggestions? Using 'in' still not too efficient tho..

Comment: @Louis_PIG A better approach would be to put `while True: d[i].remove(4)` inside of a try/except (similar to Sven's answer).

Comment: @F.J Thanks for the response. I understand Sven's answer is fast and efficient. I thought using exception to do "condition check" is not a good programing practice.

Comment: @Louis_PIG That depends on the language, in Python it is perfectly acceptable to use exceptions for something like this.  This programming style is referred to as [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp), short for "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission".

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might benefit from making your dictionary "Symmetric", you could do something like this:

```
def make_symmetric(D):
    for key, value in D.items():
        for v in value:
            D.setdefault(v, set()).add(key)

def add(D, a, b):
    D.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
    D.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)

def remove(D, a):
    values = D.pop(a)
    for v in values:
        D[v].remove(a)
```

And use it something like this:

```
>>> d = {'a': set([1, 2, 3, 4]),
         'b': set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
         'c': set([1, 2]),
         'd': set([1, 4])}
>>> make_symmetric(d)
>>> d
{1: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']),
 2: set(['a', 'c', 'b']),
 3: set(['a', 'b']),
 4: set(['a', 'b', 'd']),
 5: set(['b']),
 6: set(['b']),
 'a': set([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 'b': set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 'c': set([1, 2]),
 'd': set([1, 4])}
>>> remove(d, 4)
>>> d
{1: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']),
 2: set(['a', 'c', 'b']),
 3: set(['a', 'b']),
 5: set(['b']),
 6: set(['b']),
 'a': set([1, 2, 3]),
 'b': set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]),
 'c': set([1, 2]),
 'd': set([1])}
>>> add(d, 'd', 4)
>>> d
{1: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']),
 2: set(['a', 'c', 'b']),
 3: set(['a', 'b']),
 4: set(['d']),
 5: set(['b']),
 6: set(['b']),
 'a': set([1, 2, 3]),
 'b': set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6]),
 'c': set([1, 2]),
 'd': set([1, 4])}
```

I use sets here, but you could do something similar with lists. I wouldn't be surprised if there was already some implementation of a "symmetric" dictionary somewhere. Hopefully someone else can point you in the right direction if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you want to happen if there are duplicates in your list. The solution I've written (iterate and then remove..) doesn't handle duplicates.

```
>>> d = {'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'c':[1,2],'d':[1,4],'e':[1,4,4]}
>>> for l in d.values():
...     if 4 in l: l.remove(4)
... 
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], 'e': [1, 4], 'd': [1]}
```

This isn't very efficient though. The `if 4 in l` will iterate the list once, and the `l.remove()` will iterate the list again.

Answer (score 0):

If values contain duplicates of 4, you could use something like this:

```
d = {}                                                                                   
d['a']=[1,2,3,4]                                                                         
d['b']=[1,2,3,4,4,5,6]                                                                     
d['c']=[1,2]                                                                             
d['d']=[1,4,4,4]

def remove_dup(x,n):
    while n in x:
        x.remove(n)
    return x

for ele in d.itervalues():
    try:
        remove_dup(ele,4)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Result:

```
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], 'd': [1]}
```