# Make it so when I remove an element from one list, it's removed from another

Tags: python, list

How I can have the same element in two **different** lists, such that if I remove it from one list, it's also removed from the other?

```
a = [..., element, ...]
b = [..., element, ...]

a.remove(element)
element in b # False
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: @bernie: I think the asker is looking for the other way around; that is, two independent lists already exist, but they want them both to be affected by the same operation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: you're likely right. Wording unclear. Cheers. BrendanLong: thanks for cleaning it up, clearer now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove element in list in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934479/remove-element-in-list-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't.

In longer, to do this, you would either need to make the two lists identical, or write a wrapper around the `list` class which can take care of the removal, then make sure that both lists are an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you use element as a list, then you can stand a chance of affecting both items in a and b, when you do some operations on the list element.

```
>>> element = [10]
>>> a = [1,element,2]
>>> b = [3,element,4]
>>> a
[1, [10], 2]
>>> b
[3, [10], 4]

>>> element.pop(0)
10
>>> a
[1, [], 2]
>>> b
[3, [], 4]
>>> filter(None,a)
[1, 2]
>>> filter(None,b)
[3, 4]
```

You have to careful while doing this, because you are playing with the same instance. If you assign something else, like

```
element = 10
```

Then you are creating a new object by name element and it is no longer the one which is referenced in the list.  I find the other answer by Niklas. B, quite an interesting as well, where you are just abstracting your requirements into a class.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame, the `sprite` class has a `kill` method. When called, all spriteGroups containing the sprite will remove it from them. So if your element is not as simple as `int`, you may use this pattern.

Comment: @DavidWolever, I don't think so. Read carefully please.

Comment: Oh, yes, please forgive me. However, I'm not responsible for the downboat… So I can't help that =\